# Adding calculator to navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem. For school project I have to create app in Android Studio with few activities so i decided to add Navigation Drawer, but when i try to create simple calculator to app i can't even reference button or textview. This is code for activity where I want to create calculator. Also I have to add Map Activity and SQLite Database.

```
public class Calculator_main extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)    {

        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rootView to find your item when referencing in a Fragment:

```
public class Calculator_main extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator, container, false);

    //Notice the TextView being referenced with rootView in front of the findViewById statement 
    TextView namefield = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.namefield);

    return rootview;
   }
}
```

You need to do this when using Fragment, as this is the only way your app can reference an item in your Fragment's XML view

This is however not necessary in an Activity and should not be confused with the method of referencing in a Fragment